# How to update input value every time when you click on different button with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I just create a code where I'm using bootstrap modal, Now I need to pass multiple values to the hidden input field in the modal.

Buttons: (data-time is always unique & data-id is updated table wise)

```
<button type="button" data-id="43870" data-time="1584280862" class=" m-0 btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#swmodel"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
<button type="button" data-id="43870" data-time="1584280895" class=" m-0 btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#swmodel"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
<button type="button" data-id="43870" data-time="1584280985" class=" m-0 btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#swmodel"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
```

In Model :

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="time-name" value="" />
 <label for="message">Edit:</label>
 <textarea id="message" required="required" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

and JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#swmodel').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var Id = button.data('id');
        var time = button.data('time');
        document.getElementById('recipient-name').value = Id;
        document.getElementById('time-name').value = time;
    });
});
```

Now when I click on button its updates both values in input but when I click on another button values are not updating.

Comment: you are having three modals with the same id ?

Comment: No, I have multiple buttons that open the same model.

Comment: Please share with us all the relevant code (for example, what is `todolink`?). See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16qpkdn3/) for a working demo (I made the inputs visible so that you could see they're updated).

Comment: sorry, I just add old code, now Updated.

Comment: I see uou added `button`, but it's not defined anywhere...Besides, did you see [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16qpkdn3/)? It works, so maybe you can spot what it does differently from your code.